# Center elements at 33.3333% on the page

Tags: html, css

I have elements that are floating left and have the width of 33.33333% I am struggling to get these elements to center on the page, I still want the text inside the elements to text-align: left, but I have no idea how to center these items on the page:

```css
ul.home-product-list {}

.home-product-list li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="home-product-list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Screenshot

[image]

What do I do?

Comment: please share your markup

Comment: Can you also post the html including the container and it's respective css

Comment: there isnt a cotainer

Comment: What do you mean by "*center these items*"? Each is one third, so the middle column is *already* in the center. Are you looking to add padding or something? So that the `<ul>` has a fixed width, with margin on either side??

Comment: what exactly you want?. you want all items in a centralized row?

Comment: I guess...so my list is all the way to the left, I am looking to have these elements perfectly centred on the page.

Comment: can you put screenshot please so that i could understand what you want?

Comment: That doesn't make sense though... assuming your container is already centered (which it is by default), then the middle column is centered. Are you wanting there to only be ONE column?? Perhaps a diagram would help.

Comment: Your screenshot shows your elements correctly centered. Each item simply extends past the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `margin: 0 auto;` to items that you wanna centre them.

```css
ul.home-product-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.home-product-list li {
  width: 33.33333%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="home-product-list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container__list">
    <ul class="home-product-list">
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

    .container__list {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 960px;
    }

    ul.home-product-list {}

    .home-product-list li {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33333%;
    }
```

Hope this helps, if you are trying to center everything inside the row. Max-width could vary, I just added a random number, so you can add your custom width.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.home-product-list {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin: 0px auto; */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
 li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul class="home-product-list">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```